# Why doesn't Linux prevent spawning infinite number of processes and crashing?

Tags: c, linux

With the very simple code below, my system (Ubuntu Linux 14.04) simply crashes not even letting my mouse respond. I had to force quit with the power button. I thought Linux is a stable OS tolerable of handling such basic program errors. Did I miss something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

void check(int isOkay){
  if(!isOkay){
    printf("error\n");
    abort();
  }
}

int main(void){
  #define n 1000000
  int array[n];
  sem_t blocker;
  int i;

  while(1){
    if(!fork()){
      for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        array[i] = rand();
      }
      check(sem_init(&blocker, 0, 0) == 0);
      check(sem_wait(&blocker) == 0);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should setup ulimit if you want to limit that.

Comment: To the other fellow that flagged for closing: this isn't opinion based. There's a clear question here, but one that could be answered by a little bit of googling and a little bit less assuming of how operating systems work.

Comment: So (be honest) did you actually manage to stumble on this as a programming error while learning how to use fork()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations, you've discovered the [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).  There are shell one-liners that can wreak the same sort of havic with a lot less typing on your part.

It is in fact possible to limit the number of processes that a user can spawn using ulimit -- see the bottom of the linked wikipedia articles for details.

A desktop install of Ubuntu is not exactly a hardened server, though.  It's designed for usability first and foremost.  If you need a locked down system that can't crash, there are better options.

Comment: Ehh this isn't a fork bomb. It's just a program that erroneously forks itself (hehe) over and over again.

Comment: So, lack of intent makes it not a bomb?  Just an accidental forksplosion?

Answer (score 1):

The command `ulmit -u` shows the maximum number of processes that you can start. However, do not start that many processes in the background: your machine would spend time switching between processes and wouldn't get around to getting actual work done.

The linux does its job of processing your request to create a process, it is for the user to implement his code based on this limit.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is determining the best limit. A lot of software doesn't use `fork()` at all, so do you set the limit to something small like 5? Some software might create a new process whenever it receives a request from network, so do you set the limit to "max. number of network packets"? If you assume most software isn't buggy, then you'd be tempted to set the limit relatively high so that correct software works properly.

The other problem is one of scheduling priorities. In a well designed system things like the GUI would be "high priority" and if it wants CPU time it'd preempt normal/lower priority work immediately. If this was the case, a massive fork bomb running at normal/lower priority would have no effect on the system's ability to respond to the user, and the user would be able to kill the fork bomb without much problem.

Sadly, for a variety of reasons, the scheduler in Linux doesn't work like that. It does support priorities, but to use them you have to be a "real time" process and have to be running as root (which is a massive security disaster). Without sane priorities, Linux assumes that every forked process is as important as everything else, and the CPU/s end up busy doing the forking and there's no CPU time left to respond to the user.